# Gstreamer Extract frame from stream

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream video across a network. Currently I'm using gstreamer. However, once it gets to the other side of the network I need to be able to do add in some stuff to the frame.

I was wondering if there is a way to extract a frame from the stream, modify it and then insert it back into the stream to be displayed. If it can't be inserted back into the steam then I can use a different method to display the frames, it's the extraction that I really need to figure out.

The frame manipulation will be done using python and, once I have the correct gstreamer commands, I'll be trying to implement it in pygst.

The code to send the video:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480' !  x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

and the code to receive:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=1234 ! "application/x-rtp, payload=127" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways

1. Write a plugin : Must be comfortable with Gstreamer library
2. Use app src and app sink. 
   That will allow you to do what you want to do.

If the manipulation is better described perhaps there is a Gstreamer plugin that will help?

Comment: I'm trying to put an overlay onto the video feed while also having some of the elements interact with the feed. For example, the overlay is a fishtank and if a persons face appears on the screen then I want the fish to swim to their face.The program is designed to be a 'wormhole' between locations so if there is a person on both sides then I want the overlay to fade out so that the people can talk through the wormhole.

Comment: If you already have a component for it the appsrc and appsink will work just fine. It is exactly for the purpose you defined. There is an overlay plugin with alpha blending available but may not be capable of doing what you are asking.

Comment: +1 for the plugin. If you want to modify every frame, you want to do it from within the pipeline. Take a look at e.g. the geometrytransform plugins for examples